# How to get a GTX 1070 running on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, gpu

I tried installing driver "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27" from the offical site, but it gives out this error:

```
PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface

Using built-in stream user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 375.20 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.  For further details, please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS CHIPS in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 375.20.
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="/usr/bin/cc".
ERROR: The kernel header file '/lib/modules/4.8.4-1-ARCH/build/include/linux/kernel.h' does not exist.  The most likely reason for this is that the kernel source path '/lib/modules/4.8.4-1-ARCH/build' is incorrect.  Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files for your kernel and that they are properly configured; on Red Hat Linux systems, for example, be sure you have the 'kernel-source' or 'kernel-devel' RPM installed.  If you know the correct kernel source files are installed, you may specify the kernel source path with the '--kernel-source-path' command line option.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this warning.

> "WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 367.27 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system."

That GPU was purchased directly from MSI.

Comment: Is it 367 or 375? `nvidia-367` does support GTX 1070. You'll have to investigate how your hardware is detected on your system.

Comment: Hi I tried both the 367.27 driver and the 375.20 both versions gave me this output, do you have any suggestion as how how I could find this out I'm a bit of a newbie?

Comment: Why aren't you simply installing the `nvidia` package from the repositories?

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend reading the [Arch wiki on NVIDIA](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA) instead of downloading the drivers directly from Nvidia's website. Here's a relevant section from the wiki:

> For GeForce 400 series cards and newer [NVCx and newer], install the
>   nvidia or nvidia-lts package along with nvidia-libgl. If these
>   packages do not work, nvidia-betaAUR may have a newer driver version
>   that offers support.

So it looks like you should install the [nvidia](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=nvidia) package

```
pacman -S nvidia
```

It will then ask you whether you should other packages. Per the wiki - your card requires the [nvidia-libgl](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=nvidia-libgl) package.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue you're having is missing `kernel.h` file, which prevents drivers from being rebuilt for your system. You should install kernel header files (`linux-headers` package) and try to run the installation again.

The warning you're getting about unsupported hardware may go away once the installation succeeds. If not, you will have to investigate how your hardware is detected and why those drivers won't work with it. At this point, it will be useful to provide output of hardware diagnostic tools such as `lspci` and `lshw`.